# Unable to resolve service for type 'ClassLibrary.ApplicationDbContext' - an unhandled exception occurred

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, class-library

I have added a Class Library to my solution so that I can use Work Authentication on my ASP.Net Core site. I have been able to add a migration and update database from the PM console. However I am unable to use dotnet -ef. Upon running the site I am greeted with an unhandled exception occurred error and when researching the issue there is very little to be found, in order to solve it.

[image: An unhandled exception occurred]

Any advice in order to remedy the situation would be much appreciated, I am happy to give extra detail, as I'm not sure whether the detail that I have give is sufficient.

Comment: Have you added the reference for your class library project from web api project and have you installed ef core on your class library project?

Comment: @H.Herzl Yes, I have referenced the Class library in the web application project. Also I have installed Entity Framework Core on the Class Library.

Comment: Did you add the EF services to the service collection in the Startup ConfigureServices method? Also to get work the dotnet ef you have to specify the context's project.